# Zsh Prompt Customization

Tags: command-line, zsh

Hi I know that you set the prompt variable to edit the prompt like this

```
export PROMPT="This is the date %d"
```

How do you execute a command and print the result everytime when prompt loads.

Comment: There is usually no need to export a shells configuration parameters. `export` makes a parameter available to the environment of processes which are started later on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are actually two (main) ways to achieve this:

1. Use command substitution to run a command as part of the prompt

   ```sh
   setopt promptsubst
   PROMPT='Date %d Result $(a_command) '
   ```

   - `promptsubst` has to be enabled, else `zsh` will not do any paremeter expansions, arithmetic expansions or command substitutions.
   - Also, the prompt text needs to be quoted in such a way that the expansions are not made when setting `PROMPT`. So either put it in single quotes or, if you have/want to use double quotes, prepend `$` with a `\` to quote them separately where necessary:

     ```sh
     PROMPT="Date %d Result \$(a_command) Const $(another_command)"
     ```

     This will expand `$(another_command)` when setting `PROMPT` (so it is run only once and its result than substituted permanently) and `$(a_command)` every time the prompt is shown.
2. Make use of the `precmd` function (or hook) and the `psvar` array:

   ```sh
   autoload -Uz add-zsh-hook
   a_function () {
       psvar[1]=$(a_command)
   }
   two_function () {
       psvar[2]=$(two_command)
   }
   add-zsh-hook precmd a_function
   add-zsh-hook precmd two_function
   PROMPT='Date %d Result1 %v Result2 %2v '
   ```

   - If set, the `precmd` function is run just before the prompt is printed. You can also set a list of functions to run in the `precmd_functions` array.
   - `add-zsh-hook` provides an easy way to add functions to that array.
   - `%Nv` in the prompt is replaced by the N-th element of the `psvar` array. If `N` is left out (`%v`) `N==1` is assumed (this is also true for other prompt token that take numeric arguments)

On first glance the second method may look far more complicated then just using `promptsubst`. But this is only the case for very simple substitutions. Using `precmd` allows for using more complex functions without making the definition of `PROMPT` unreadable due to cramming several lines of code inside a `$( )`.

You can also combine both approaches and forego the use of `psvar` in some or all cases:

```sh
autoload -Uz add-zsh-hook
setopt promptsubst
a_function () {
    a_parameter=$(a_command)
}
two_function () {
    psvar[2]=$(two_command)
}
add-zsh-hook precmd a_function
add-zsh-hook precmd two_function
PROMPT='Date %d Result ${a_parameter} %2v'
```

Comment: `$(...)` is *command* substitution. Process substitution is something else, usually used with I/O redirection.

Comment: You are of course correct. Thanks for the catch, I fixed it.