# zsh prompt not evaluating colors correctly

Tags: shell, zsh

My .zshrc:

```
parse_git_branch() {
    git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}

cNone='\033[00m'
cRed='\033[01;31m'
cGreen='\033[01;32m'
cYellow='\033[01;33m'
cPurple='\033[01;35m'
cCyan='\033[01;36m'
cWhite='\033[01;37m'
cBold='\033[1m'
cUnderline='\033[4m'

COLOR="\033[32m\]"
export PS1="(parse_git_branch) %~ ${cRed}♥ "
```

Output:

```
(parse_git_branch) ~/someDirectory/Another \033[01;32m♥
```

Not sure why it isn't escaping the colors correctly nor why it isn't evaluating the git branch command.

Comment: bash, or zsh? They're completely different, intentionally incompatible shells (as bash chooses to be a superset of POSIX sh, and zsh chooses to be incompatible in places where its authors consider the standard to make no sense); a question should only tag one or the other, not both.

Comment: Why it's not running the function is simple, by the way -- you'd need to make it `$(parse_git_branch)` to do so; the leading `$` is missing. (And put that in **single quotes**, not double quotes, to defer its execution).

Comment: Also, don't `export` your `PS1` -- that could result in child processes without the `parse_git_branch` function defined trying to use it.

Comment: Also, don't hardcode color sequences -- they're not universal across all terminals. Use `tput` to retrieve the correct values for your individual terminal, as described in [BashFAQ #37](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/037).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy sorry, zsh. I updated it to look like this: `export PS1="$(parse_git_branch) %~ ${cRed}♥ "` Not sure where the single quotes are supposed to go. It now doesn't literally output "parse_git_branch" but the function never evaluates to anything. What should this line look like?

Comment: `PS1='$(parse_git_branch) %~ ...etc...'"$cRed"'...other literal contents...'` -- only things intended to be expanded at assignment time belong in single quotes. And no `export`.

Comment: Also, using ANSI escape codes for font settings is mostly unnecessary in `zsh` because it already has an easy way to set colors in prompts: PS1="$(parse_git_branch) %~ %B%F{red}♥ %f%b". `%F{<COLOR>}` sets the foreground color, `%B` enables bold, `%f` resets to the default foreground color and `%b` disables bold.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, according to http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html, zsh supports using **%F** to start font color and **%f** to stop font color:

> Start (stop) using a different foreground colour, if supported by the terminal. The colour may be specified two ways: either as a numeric argument, as normal, or by a sequence in braces following the %F, for example %F{red}.

To make a red ♥: `%F{red}♥%f`

Secondly, to fetch the git branch name, there is an easier way:

`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD 2> /dev/null`

Thirdly, in order to run command inside prompt `setopt prompt_subst` is required

Finally, here is your colorful prompt:

`setopt prompt_subst
PS1='$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD 2> /dev/null) %~ %F{red}♥%f '`

If you want to use " (double quotes) instead of ' (single quotes), a \ (backslash) is needed before $:

`setopt prompt_subst
PS1="\$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD 2> /dev/null) %~ %F{red}♥%f "`

More info can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/a/36196179/8272771

Comment: I can't get colorization to work around the function call. Try: ```setopt PROMPT_SUBST

PROMPT='%F{green}[$(parse_git_branch)]%f %# '```
You'll see the opening bracket '[' being green but everything after is white again. Seems that the '$' sign messes with the colorization.

Comment: What's the output of the function `parse_git_branch`? I guess it may cause the problem you have. If the output of this function contains `%f`, it will stop text color and turn color to white after it. I'd suggest to replace `parse_git_branch` by another function or some static strings to see if text color works or not.